# Multiple SQLs on a temp table failed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Spark Version: 1.6.2.
```

I registered a temporary table, whose data source is HDFS, and do query twice on it.

Then job failed with this error:

> ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
>   java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://my_server:8020/2017/01/01
>   java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://my_server:8020/2017/01/01
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:322)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)

Tricky part is that job succeeded if only one query is run.
Do I use Spark SQL in the wrong way, or is this intended?

This is what my code looks like:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://my_server:8020/2017/*/*/*")
val table = sqlc.read.json(rdd).cache()

table.registerTempTable("my_table")

sql("""
    | SELECT contentsId,
    |   SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)
    | FROM my_table
    | GROUP BY contentsId
  """.stripMargin)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .save("hdfs://my_server:8020/gender.csv")

sql("""
    | SELECT contentsId,
    |   SUM(CASE WHEN age > 0 AND age < 20 then 1 else 0 end),
    |   SUM(CASE WHEN age >= 20 AND age < 30 then 1 else 0 end)
    | FROM my_table
    | GROUP BY contentsId
  """.stripMargin)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .save("hdfs://my_server:8020/age.csv")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you trying to save two different dataframes in a single output file as gender.csv?

Comment: Error Indicates its not able to read file Not a file: hdfs://my_server:8020/2017/01/01    <--? is it a file or empty directory?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala My mistake. Saving them in two different files is what I need to do. I edited query.

Comment: @Bhavesh `hdfs://my_server:8020/2017/01/01` is a directory. Moreover, this exception only occurs when two queries are in a job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try applying filter only for files something like this.

```
val filesRDD = rdd.filter{path => (new java.io.File(path).isFile)}
```

This will remove all the Directories that are contain in RDD 
And also for second time saving the DataFrame use this

```
sql("""
    | SELECT contentsId,
    |   SUM(CASE WHEN age > 0 AND age < 20 then 1 else 0 end),
    |   SUM(CASE WHEN age >= 20 AND age < 30 then 1 else 0 end)
    | FROM my_table
    | GROUP BY contentsId
  """.stripMargin)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .mode("append")
  .save("hdfs://my_server:8020/gender.csv")
```

If storing values are same Or try storing Second DataFrame into some different file

Comment: Filtering path is a good idea, but the point is that exception only occurs when two queries are in a job though. :-( Could you add more declaration of time saving part?